# Head Request Returns a 403

Tags: amazon-cloudfront

When I make a HEAD request for a URL with `curl -I` I get a 403 error:

```
HTTP/2 403
content-type: application/xml
date: Wed, 22 Aug 2018 15:50:29 GMT
server: AmazonS3
x-cache: Error from cloudfront
via: 1.1 bfda628fa09b80e042e2c85c85acf1c7.cloudfront.net (CloudFront)
x-amz-cf-id: ryZHGZJ1cKbIa-n1Oxznge9MYl7C2-btqva9W0wQTvooVd6vzAaktw==
```

When I make the full request with just `curl` it works fine. I've verified that the behavior is set up with Allowed HTTP Methods GET and HEAD. What am I missing?

Comment: Does your origin allow HEAD?

Comment: @cementblocks the origin is S3 and I don't see anywhere that we are permitting or denying HEAD requests

Comment: A couple things to try to troubleshoot. Turn on s3 access logs for your bucket. Add s3:ListBucket on the bucket arn (no trailing /*) in your bucket policy. (If you don't have list bucket permissions you get 403 instead of 404 if the object doesn't exist).

Comment: I found that if I make the HEAD request without any of the parameters it works. When I make the HEAD request with a signed request, I get the 403. That would seem like a problem with the signature, but it works when it isn't a HEAD request?

Comment: @cementblocks are you available to consult? :)